# What is the regular expression for whole/decimal numbers that have a maximum length of 16?

Tags: regex

What is the regular expression for whole/decimal numbers that have a maximum length of 16 (including one comma*)?

Valid Examples

```
12345689012345,

0,12345678901234

123,123

123456789,012345

1,
```

Invalid Examples

```
,1

,123467890123456

123,,123

1,1,
```

*the comma acts as a decimal point

**I have tried using this `[0-9]{1,16},[0-9]{1,16}?**

However, it does not limit the total length of numbers to 16 and gives it a length of 32.

**I have also tried this one ([0-9]+([,][0-9]+?)?){0,15}**

The problem with this one is that it does not limit the numbers and only allows this format numbers,numbers (ex. 123,123)

Comment: As you've approached asking this question in a "give me the code for this problem" kind of way, your best bet is to go [here](https://regex101.com/) and read the reference (bottom right) while playing with different combinations until you get the result you were after.

Comment: @Marty I apologize if I seem to ask for the code but I've tried several combinations and yet I can't seem to get the right one. I'll edit my post and put in the combinations I have tried.

Comment: That will really help your question :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a negative look ahead to eliminate more than one comma and anchors:

```
^(?!.*,.*,)(\d[\d,]{0,15})$

^                           ^    anchors
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  start with a digit then digits and comma up to 1+15
   ^^^^^^ UNLESS there is more than one comma
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lS1tF8/4)

Comment: Thanks for your help dawg and also for giving a demo.